# how to host laravel api on heroku and the database on a shared hosting

Tags: laravel

i am trying to host a laravel api on heroku and the database on a shared hosting. on my system locally the database connects to the shared hosting put after uploading o heroku it denies me access.

i checked online on how to deploy laravel to heroku the laravel page works but when i go to https://sahara-api.herokuapp.com/api/users on postman acccess denied and it works locally

```
    $users  = users::all();
    $response =[  'users'=> $users ];
    return response()->json($response, 200);

    }


    public function post_users(Request $request){


        $users = new users();   
         $users->user_name= $request->input('user_name');
         $users->user_pass= $request->input('user_pass');
         $users->user_email= $request->input('user_email');
         $users->category_id= $request->input('category_id');


          $users->save();  



         if($users->save()){

            return response()->json(['message'=> 'success '],201) ;

        } 
    else{
      return response()->json(['message'=> 'bad api authentication'],201) ;
    }




         }
```

to get results from the users table on my shared hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your .env file there is extra space in database password. 
[image]

Comment: one more thing set APP_DEBUG = false. Your database credentials are leaking in exception page

Comment: the database password connects to the shared hosting fine

Comment: I tried logging into database from these credentials. I have to remove extra space to connect. So, I think the one of many problems is extra space. I have pasted the screenshot. You can see there is extra space in password

Comment: i checked the env file on my system there is no extra space between DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx so is it on heroku and it connects to the db on the shared hosting locally with postman

Comment: space is not in between DB_PASSWORD=xxxxxx it is in end. Can you please send the screenshot of error you're getting now. Just see the highlighted text above image you can see the space between ^ & '

Comment: DB_PASSWORD=2Onc=00LcX}^  this is how it is in my env

Comment: guy thanks. your programming skills is on fire, this is some next level programming

Comment: Thanks, I suggest to change DB password since it is now public